# CRS projection problem when I reproject my shapefile and raster

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have two layer, shapefile and raster. I need to re project shape-file into  EPSG:32633 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N . I did it using this python code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Path to the original shapefile
shapefile = r'2019_ID69.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)

print("Original CRS: ", gdf.crs)
if gdf.crs != 'EPSG:32633':
    gdf = gdf.to_crs('EPSG:32633')
    print("Reprojected CRS: ", gdf.crs)
else:
    print("No reprojection needed.")

# Define the output path for the new shapefile
output_shapefile_path = r'reprojected_2019.shp'

# Save the GeoDataFrame as a shapefile
gdf.to_file(output_shapefile_path)
```

I also reproject it through data management in QGIS . However in both cases my shapefile is not in the correct place (based on base map) and not aligned with my raster layer (EPSG:32633 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N)

Comment: what projection is your shapefile in to start with?

Comment: What projection is your vector layer in and what projection is set for the QGIS project? Is the vector layer aligned with the raster layer before the reprojection?

Comment: when I use EPSG 4326/WGS84 for the shapefile and EPSG:32633 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N for my raster file they are aligned. but when I reproject my shapefile to the same one with raster it doesnt aligned. I know theses two layesr are in different project system but I need to extract information  from tif layer and they should be in the same projection for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add the solution to my question here, it was very basic but I did not know and it might be useful for another beginner person, I changed the name of my files and it affected the projection. otherwise the above code could help to reproject.